# Sonoma 14.0 can't connect to linux Samba server V.3

Tags: macos, smb

I have a long-running linux Samba server version V 4.3, and since upgrading a Mac to Sonoma I can't connect to it anymore.

```
mount_smbfs //user@server/share ./localmt
mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error
```

Do I have to upgrade the Samba server or is there something I can do with the samba configuration or on the macOS  client side?

Comment: And if you specify a username and a password?  How is the share configured?

Comment: Please update the question with the smb.conf in code tags. You can anonymise any share names if you want, but be sure to include the shares, as relevant bits of config are in those sections. Otherwise it might be as simple as checking and updating the Samba version (I'm running 4.13 with no issue), or if your minimum protocol version (if specified) needs upping. Or even rerunning `smbpasswd` for the relevant user.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am on Sonoma version 14.3

Comment: Asking a new question that links here and provides some of the extra details (see above comments) where your setup differs would be a good thing @BirgitDucarroz if no one has a one line fix for you here in comments...

Answer (score 1):

I upgrading to Sonoma version 14.1 and the problem went away for me.

Before upgrading Sonoma, I turned on more advanced logging at the linux SMB server side, and found these error messages:

```
ntlm_password_check: Lanman passwords NOT PERMITTED for user username
NO LanMan password set for user username (and no NT password supplied)
```

(I had no problems with another Linux server running Samba 4.15.)